# Stored procedure call in Hibernate throws 'Could not read column value from result set'

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an java Object `Person` with 3 properties `firstname`, `lastname` and `username`.

I have an Oracle stored procedure returning a result set with the 3 columns. 
All works fine for that.

Now I have another stored procedure that will only return firstname and lastname but not username.

I get the following error:

> Could not read column value from result set username

Hibernate tries to fetch the username property from the resultset.
If I remove the property username, then it works.

My config:

```
<sql-query name="normalise" callable="true" >
<return alias="val" class="com.nbfg.sipc.model.Person">
<return-property name="firstname" column="FIRST_NAME"/>
<return-property name="lastname" column="LASTNAME_NAME"/>
</return>
{call SCHSIPC.PKG_SIPC_APP.PRC_SIPC_NORMALISE_RS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }
</sql-query>
```

My Pojo (no annotation)

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
...
```

The call:

```
private Value call(String app, String cat, String col, String valeure, String query) {
    try {
        Query q = getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession().getNamedQuery(query);
        q.setString(0, app).setString(1, cat).setString(2, col).setString(3, valeure);
        return (Person) q.list().get(0);
    } catch (org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

It all works fine if I remove the property `username` from my Pojo. I can I reuse the same PoJo?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the code. I am not 100% certain on this, but I believe that with Hibernate SQL queries must return all fields of the object you want the query to instantiate.

An alternative solution you may want to try is to rely on HQL and instantiate the object as needed. For example, SELECT new Person(firstName, lastName) from Person p where p.username = ...
This actually allows you to use any type (with fields of matching types) in your queries.

This would solve your immediate problem, but I am not sure how to address the use of stored procedures in this scenario. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are working with a simplistic stored proc that just does a simple select and returns the table schema (like you would with .NET), I would dispense with the stored procedure entirely. Let hibernate handle the associations, and generate the proper SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guest if we are saying that there is no way to tell Hibernate to read only certain columns in a result set returned by a stored procedure and that I need to create a separate POJO for each type of result set, then this the answer.

If this right?

Comment: As far as I know that's correct. But read the Hibernate documentation... The question then becomes, do you really need to rely on the stored procedures? You definitely don't want to have one POJO per query, all more or less representing the same object. Have your POJOs, let them define useful queries in HQL and let for eg a SLSB offer clients to execute these queries. Clean and simple. Unless, you have to have the stored procs.